# How much time to reserve for a visit to Mucha Museum in Prague?

Tags: planning, museums, czech-republic, prague, artworks

Roughly how long do people take on average when visiting the Mucha Museum in Prague, say is it an hour or two, half day or all day?

I am trying to plan a day in Prague and I can't find any proper information on the other websites.

Comment: Unanswerable. You can spend half an hour or half a year at any large enough museum, depending on your own preferences.

Comment: IMO, guidebooks and travel websites provide enough information that it's perfectly possible to provide a reasonable answer to questions like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The museum is quite small - 2 or 3 rooms, as I recall.  Reviews on TripAdvisor suggest 1-2 hours, depending on whether you care to watch the the half hour documentary on his life.  Personally, I didn't watch the entire film, and probably spent under an hour there, and I felt like I had a fairly comprehensive view of all the exhibits.  Obviously if you're an artist or someone who can view the exhibits at a much more detailed level than I can, you could take longer.

I would recommend [contacting the museum about their guided tours](http://www.mucha.cz/index.phtml?S=guid&Lang=EN) and asking how long those take.

Answer (score 5):

I like Mucha’s style a great deal (his women are incredibly sexy), but 2 hours is enough. Better to see his Slav Epic at the [Trade fair palace](http://www.ngprague.cz/en/objekt-detail/veletrzni-palace/), if it still be there. There was some dispute over a permanent home.

Answer (score 4):

Slav Epic is on the tour, so not available in Prague, but that would be well worth seeing.  Mucha Museum is privately owned and I feel expensive for such a small area and you would probably be better off visiting The National Galery - Veletrzni Palac, Address: Dukelských Hrdinů 530/47, 170 00 Praha 7-Holešovice, easy to get there by tram. The international collection includes numerous works by artists such as Picasso, Monet, Van Gogh, Rodin, Gauguin, Cézanne, Renoir, Schiele, Munch, Miró and Klimt and yes also Mucha and many Czech artists.  It will take you several hours.